# How to have two different UX/UI for a PhoneGap application

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

I am building a PhoneGap cross platform hybrid application.
In my application I have support for iPad and iPhone.
User interface for both the devices is different but business logic is same.

So question is how can I have tow different user interface (HTML/CSS) for two different devices, using common business logic code (JavaScript) for both the devices.

I want to just rewrite UX/UI of the application and reuse the business logic related code, how can I design my application to do so.

Comment: If you're using Ionic, you can have your UI be 'responsive' and you can also use different icons for different sized screens and use separate icons for iPhone and Android.

Answer (score 1):

First off you'll need to detect the platform you're running. There are many ways to achieve this but I'll just go with a simple example (and assume you're using jQuery too)

```
if ( navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="ipad.css">');
}else if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) ){
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="iphone.css">');
}else{
    // up to you here
}
```

There are much better ways of detecting the platform but that will do for starters.

Answer (score 1):

Some JavaScript front end frameworks (e.g. Ionic, Sencha Touch) support themes and you can use those to render different UX based on the device type whilst sharing the logic.  Having a Model View Controller architecture for your JavaScript would assist here also.

Rather than trying to match user agents yourself you probably want to use the [Cordova Device plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mp-cordova-plugin-device) to determine which device you are running on and react accordingly, you can also use CSS media queries as you would for a regular responsive web app / site.  It may be helpful to use something like an ["is tablet" plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.istablet) if you want to distinguish phones from tablets and aren't using a JS framework that can do this for you.

At a platform level (rather than devices), a feature of Cordova that's not well understood but could help you here would be the ['merges'](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/guide/cli/#using-merges-to-customize-each-platform) concept, which allows you to create new CSS/JS/images/whatever per platform and have those merged in with the contents or your www folder during the build process.